# My htaccess doesn’t remove extension .php

Tags: php

I‘ve defined three htaccess in a folder called env_files, and I have other .htaccess inner public file:

[image: screen]

All htaccess code is right:

```
# development
DirectoryIndex index.php
#Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 error404
ErrorDocument 500 error404

RewriteEngine On

# REDIRECTS FROM WWW TO NON www URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# AVOID URL END DOT (COOKIE PROBLEMS) mydomayin.com. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)\.$
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

# REMOVE EXTENSION .PHP
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|flv|pdf|woff|eot|svg|ttf|flv|swf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=29030400"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

    ## Desactiva la firma del servidor ##
ServerSignature Off
```

But my website doesn‘t load the pages.php without .php extension:
http://calendario-online.es/calendario-laboral-2015-cordoba

If you write ".php" in the end of URL, the page load.

Why this is happening?

Comment: You have a set of `RewriteCond`s, but no `RewriteRule` to follow if the conditions are met.

Answer (score 0):

Try use this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try with this:

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Below .htaccess code may help you to solve your issue

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```